# How I can display user profile picture on view laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, web, developer-tools

Im having trouble when I try to display the user profile picture from logged user, I have my view called DayRequest, but I can't make Laravel to show the user profile image, the image is stored in a different computer with the IP 10.57.2.98 I have the image address stored in a SQL Server Column, called Fotografia, and fotografia field has \10.57.2.98\Fotos_Empleados\userid.jpg

I tried   `<img src="10.57.2.98\Fotos_Empleados\10044.jpg"  class="user-image" alt="User Image">`

and    `<img src="{{\\10.57.2.98\Fotos_Empleados\10044.jpg}}"  class="user-image" alt="User Image">`

and my output shows 10.57.6.94\Fotos_Empleados\10044.jpg It doesn't show anything, please help thanks

Comment: Can you access to `http://10.57.6.94/Fotos_Empleados/10044.jpg` in your browser?

Comment: Shows 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: If your browser can't access the file it will not be able to show it. This is as simple as that.

Comment: there is something I can do to show it?

Answer (score 0):

Your server shows nothing even in browser, so this is not laravel syntax issue, check your images server to send valid response.

Comment: what do you mean to check my images server? what do I need to check? I´m sorry im newbie at laravel

Comment: just past this url to browser address line and hit enter, do you get the image?
10.57.2.98\Fotos_Empleados\10044.jpg

Comment: That's why it can't be loaded in img tag, your server does not send image as a response, first fix that issue

Comment: How I can fix this? I'm sorry im little bit new at laravel, and is the first time I try to retrieve an image from the server

Comment: That server doesn't respond and this is not a Laravel issue, and i cant't tell you how to fix the server because i have no information about that server. I can suggest you to use your server, retrieve images from your storage or public directory